# Grovvy script filename

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How do I get the name of the current Groovy script filename? It's a Jenkins scripted pipeline.

Tried, but didn't work:

- this.class.getName()
- this.class.name
- getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path

Who can help me?
bg